# Focusrite Scarlet 2i2 Cubase

Tags: audio, software, music, playback, signal-routing

I recently purchased the Focusrite Scarlet 2i2 interface which comes with  Cubase Music Recording Software, and I've been extremely frustrated with my sound when attempting to playback after recording.

I have success with recording my material, because the material is present in the editing window; however, I cannot get the sound to play back.

Can anyone please offer me some troubleshooting suggestions. (I've watched, and followed along with a Cubase tutorial on YouTube several times.)

My speakers are patched correctly (I believe I'm not assigning my outputs correctly in the software.)

Comment: Which very specific version of cubase did your Scarlett interface come with? I'm looking for something like "Cubase LE 8.3".

Comment: Which youtube vide did you watch (link please)

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume it's a problem with audio signal flow within Cubase (the version I'm going off of is Cubase 7 or 8 Pro):

- In `Devices > Device Setup...`, under `VST Audio System`, make sure that your device driver is the one selected in the dropdown menu at the top of the window.
- In the same menu, click on your device name in the list under `VST Audio System` and make sure that all the ports are checked as active.
- Under `Devices > VST Connections` (<kbd>F4</kbd>), make sure that you have connected your device's outputs to Stereo Out, or whatever sort of connection scheme you want. You may have to click `Add Bus` in order to set this up.
- Once that is set up, you then need to make sure that each individual track is routed to the master bus so that the master bus can send audio out to your device. Track routing controls can be edited either via the mixer (<kbd>F3</kbd>) or by the track inspector at the left of the timeline.

Once all that's taken care of, your playback should be functional. That's assuming, of course, that this is just an audio routing issue. I have had my fair share of frustrating *this should just be working* moments, and hopefully this checklist will solve your issue.